# Trabalhando com resources C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Adicionei o resource de dicionários ao meu projeto, agora preciso converter ele em um dicionario via código, mas está trazendo o recurso nulo, alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
List<string> dic = new List<string>();
List<string> aff = new List<string>();

Assembly _assembly;
StreamReader _textStreamReader;

_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string line;

_textStreamReader = new StreamReader(
    _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("tx_spell_open_dict_resource.pt_BR.dic"));
while ((line = _textStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    dic.Add(line);
}

_textStreamReader = new StreamReader(
    _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("tx_spell_open_dict_resource.pt_BR.aff"));
while ((line = _textStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    aff.Add(line);
}

OpenOfficeDictionary dic_ptBR = new OpenOfficeDictionary(
    dic.ToArray(), aff.ToArray(), new CultureInfo("pt_BR"));
txSpellChecker1.Dictionaries.Add(dic_ptBR);
```

Talvez a parte errada , esteja na string que tento pegar o resource.

Comment: Em qual linha ou linhas está acontecendo isso?

Comment: No momento em que estou dando `GetManifestResouceStream`

Comment: O nome do `tx_spell_open_dict_resource.pt_BR.dic` seria `tx_spell_open_dict_resource.pt_BR.dic.resx`?

Comment: Da uma olhada ve se ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w

Comment: Dei uma olhada , mais infelizmente não é isso o problema.  tentei renomear com o namespace, mesmo assim ele retornar nulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verin,

Utilizo da seguinte forma.

Crio um arquivo de nome Resources.resx em Properties.
Em seguida crio os arquivos com os nomes Resources.pt-BR.resx, Resources.en-US.resx e etc.

Crio a strings iguais nos 3 arquivos (ou nos demais idiomas que preciso).

Para traduzir textos específicos utilizo esta função que montei:

```
    public static string Tradutor(string pVariavel)
    {
        try
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));
            return rm.GetString(pVariavel);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Variável não localizada.";
        }
    }
```

Na entrada da classe BaseController (aqui utilizo MVC).

```
/*CULTUREINFO DO USUÁRIO*/
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

A chamada do pt-BR é só para exemplo, você inclui de acordo com a forma que armazena esta variável.

Está é a forma simples, fora as outras integrações, como por exemplo utilizar no DataAnnotations dentro de Views e etc.